# xcode swift app, location works on simulator but not on actual device

Tags: xcode, swift

i am making a running (jogging) app for apple using xcode and swift, the version of xcode i am on is 7.0/7.1 When you start a new run, a map comes up and tracks where you are running along with displaying time, distance, and pace. This all works when i use the debug simulator, but when i put it on the device, an ipad running ios 8.4, which i have the app developed for, the map comes up but does not show the location so it cant calculate distance or pace and when you try to save the run i get an error of no location was found. not sure what to check for in the code that would be different on the actual device compared to working on the simulator. I tried a couple of things i found on this site and they did not work. i turned off simulate location and set the debug simulation to none. after i did that i deleted the app on the device, exited xcode restarted and rebuilt it on the device. Thanks for any help

```
  @IBAction func startPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    startButton.hidden = true
    promptLabel.hidden = true

    timeLabel.hidden = false
    distanceLabel.hidden = false
    paceLabel.hidden = false
    stopButton.hidden = false

    seconds = 0.0
    distance = 0.0
    locations.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "eachSecond:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startLocationUpdates()

    mapView.hidden = false
  }

    > // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate extension NewRunViewController:
    > CLLocationManagerDelegate {   func locationManager(manager:
    > CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    >     for location in locations as! [CLLocation] {
    >       let howRecent = location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

      if abs(howRecent) < 10 && location.horizontalAccuracy < 20 {
        //update distance
        if self.locations.count > 0 {
          distance += location.distanceFromLocation(self.locations.last)

          var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
          coords.append(self.locations.last!.coordinate)
          coords.append(location.coordinate)

          let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 500, 500)
          mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

          mapView.addOverlay(MKPolyline(coordinates: &coords, count: coords.count))
        }

        //save location
        self.locations.append(location)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask for user permission to use his GPS location ? And did you add keys to Info.plist :

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Get Your Location </string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Get Your Location For </string>
```

Could you post your code ?

Comment: yes i did the and it pops up once i go to the new run page before the run actually starts